# Create object of ClassA by using an object of ClassB

Tags: java, maven, design-patterns

I have two Maven projects (libraries) ProjectA and ProjectB.
ProjectA has ClassA and ProjectB has a similar ClassB.

Currently both classes have constructors that take instances of the equivalent other class.
Because of that, ProjectA and ProjectB mutually depend on each other.

Now I would like to (re-)move the dependency, so that the dependency is only needed for Maven projects that explicitly want to construct As using Bs or vice versa?

What design pattern should I use? Factory? Builder? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see to do this is to provide interfaces is some third project. Have the constructors that take the opposite project's class take the interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have cyclic dependency with maven. because you can make sense that if you are trying to add that kind of cyclic dependency, there is an issue to decide which project build first? So you can refactor your project in to proper way that avoid cyclic dependancy.